# Request Permissions

Tags: android

I'm working on an app that allows the user to upload files on a server.
I need to request permissions but the app isn't showing me the dialog box that ask permissions.
Ps. I added permissions in the manifest.

Java code

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        //requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        //requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]
                {Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
    }
}

public void Upload()
{

    TextView Result= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Conn);
    String URL= ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.URL)).getText().toString();
    String Username= ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username)).getText().toString();
    String Password= ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Password)).getText().toString();
    FTPClient FTPClient=new FTPClient();
    FTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    try {
        InetAddress indirizzo = InetAddress.getByName(URL);
        FTPClient.connect(indirizzo);
        Result.setText(FTPClient.getReplyString());
        //aperta la connessione al server procedo al login

        boolean login=FTPClient.login(Username,Password);
        if(login==true)
            Result.append(" ..login effettuato");

        else Result.append("...login fallito");

        //apro il file contenuto nel path /sdcard come stream
        /*client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE); // imposto il tipo di dati, da modificare a seconda dell'utilità
        File sdcardDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); //dato che il mio file era sulla sd prendo il riferimento alla memoria       esterna
        File file = new File(sdcardDir,"fotografia.jpeg"); //prendo il riferimento al file salvato sulla sd
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);//creo uno stream in input a partire dal mio file

        //risposta.append("...path file: " + file.getPath()); //questa istruzione la usavo per test, la lascio casomai dovesse servire, stampa semplicemente il path del file che voglio uploadare

        boolean upload_ok=client.storeFile("fotografia.jpeg", fis);
        fis.close();//procedo alla chiusura dello stream, infatti storeFile non chiude fis
        if(upload_ok==true)risposta.append("  ..... upload ok");
        else risposta.append("....upload fallito, errore: " + upload_ok);*/

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {

            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission granted
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

            else {

                // permission denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}`

Sorry for every trouble i'm causing to you and my bad english, maybe it's a simple thing but i'm still learning

Comment: Are you sure, you are testing this code for right device which has bigger version than Android M? Also, make sure you don't have permissions at beginning.  Can you check your permissions by using ContextCompat. checkSelfPermission and display your logs ?

Comment: Yep i'm using on a device that have Android N and the permissions are denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query for both permissions at once:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]
            {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 1);
```

Then add switch for requested permission string in the callback.

You might also want to add [`shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)). If user checked "don't ask again" during request, dialog won't show anymore.

Comment: I wrote both permissions at one but now ask just the first permission maybe the Internet permission doesn't need that the user accept it. I'm adding the switch in the callback.